# How to prevent hide toolbar by scroll itself

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, appbar

I have problem with CoordinatorLayout and behavior of Toolbar.
As usual I want to hide/show toolbar by scroll.And it is work fine.But if I fling on Toolbar itself it will hide independently of recyclerView or everything else.
How to prevent Toolbar hide/show behavior by touching toolbar itself.

Here is video that  explain my issue.
https://youtu.be/3bFcy2SF3Nk

For additional info here is snippet from my layout file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_dark" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

okey i see your video and i have same problem in past
The answer is this :
When you click on icon in bottom bar to new fragment load do this :

## For Disable :

```
  Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  // or however you need to do it for your code
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
```

And when click on home botton in bottom bar do it to enable Scroll toolbar:

## For Enable :

```
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
    | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Thank You for answer, it possibly can work, but it is not so clear solution.And for me after disabling enable do not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  >
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_dark" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </FrameLayout>﻿
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank You for answer, but it not work for me.
I have to use CoordinatorLayout to achieve correct behavior of toolbar and bottom navigation.And RecyclerView insode ScrollView is not a good practice.And after applying you example Toolbar still hide after fling on it.